# unique_ptr usage for legacy functions

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the code

```
struct Resource
{
    Resource()
    {
        std::cout << "C";
    }
    ~Resource()
    {
        std::cout << "D";
    }
};

void allocate(Resource **p)
{
    *p = new Resource();
}

int main()
{
    Resource *p = nullptr;
    allocate(&p);
    std::unique_ptr<Resource> uptr(p);

    //stuff
}
```

Assuming that 'allocate' function is heavily used in legacy code in multiple call sites, the main function shows an attempt to use unique_ptr to manage the allocated resource. The problem occurs when another programmer on the team writes exception prone code after 'allocate' and before 'unique_ptr' gets to own it.

So, one solution that comes to my mind is to write code which leverages the comma operator as follows

```
std::unique_ptr<Resource> up((allocate(&p), p));
```

Is there another reasonable way to handle this situation? Basic problem is to make alllocation and ownership  as an atomic operation.

Comment: In this specific case, you could have a function that just returns the pointer: `Resource *allocate() { Resource *result; allocate(&result); return result; }`, and then use that function: `std::unique_ptr<Resource> up(allocate());` Is your real problem more general, and if so, can you edit your question to include cases that cannot be solved like that?

Comment: how about wrapping the `allocate` function such that, it'll return a moved `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: As I mentioned, allocate is a heavily used function and I don't see changing it signature right away. So, in the sense it is a slow but steady adoptance of C++11 concepts in the product

Comment: @Chubsdad: Nobody suggested changing it. They're talking about wrapping it. But then your colleagues have to remember to use the wrapper rather than the original function, or the entire purpose is moot, and if they were aware enough of the problems you've described to remember to do that, then they wouldn't have written exception-prone code there in the first place!

Comment: Which means I need to change all the call sites. May be we will get there but not immediately...

Comment: @Chubsdad Only in the same way you'd have to change all the call sites to use your comma operator solution. If you wrap it, there's no reason you can't leave some code using the original function while new code uses the wrapper function.

Comment: I agree, and that's why I posted the query. Is there a supported or an idiomatic way to handle such category of functions?

Comment: @Chubsdad Ideally you could refactor the existing function name to something incomprehensible, e.g.  `old_crappy_allocate_that_no_sane_person_would_ever_accidentally_type()`, and define a new `allocate()` that returns a `unique_ptr`. That way the old code keeps working, but it's easier for programmers not to screw up in new code by inadvertently using the old function.

Answer (score 2):

For the smoothest transition, create an overload of `allocate`:

```
template <typename T>
void allocate(std::unique_ptr<T>* p) {
  T* raw;
  allocate(&raw)
  p->reset(raw);
}
```

Existing call sites will continue to work unchanged. When you update a call site, you replace the raw pointer with a `unique_ptr`, and remove whatever line frees the resource, but otherwise keep the code unchanged. (Replace places where the raw pointer is passed with `.get()`.)

Comment: I think I would simply return the `unique_ptr` by value and get rid of the weird "pass-pointer-to-return-value" calling convention.

Comment: @Casey well, he did say "smooth transition" - `std::unique_ptr<Resource> uptr; allocate(&uptr);` vs `Resource* p; allocate(&p);`

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do that is to return a `unique_ptr` from an overloaded function:

```
std::unique_ptr<Resource> allocate()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<Resource>(new Resource());
}
```

Comment: About the edit: Isn't the `unique_ptr` constructor called automatically?

Comment: [No, the constructor is `explicit`.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb91b33a7f0958bc "Demo at Coliru")

Comment: the reason for downvote is, that the OP doesn't want to change the call signature.

Comment: Don't change the call signature then. This will work fine as an overload.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I rather like your comma solution. Of course, you still need your forgetful exception-happy programmers to remember to use it, so it doesn't work as a catch-all fix.

In fact, on that basis, there isn't one.